# Getting DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope instead of Constructor

Tags: react-native, scrollview

When I print **this** inside of onScroll handler I get 
**DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope** instead of **Constructor**.

```
var Frame = React.createClass({
    _handleScroll: (ev) => {
        console.log(this) //DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ScrollView
                ref='scrollViewH'
                onScroll={this._handleScroll}>
                {items}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
});
```

If I handle scroll with inline function this works correct:

```
var Frame = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ScrollView
                ref='scrollViewH'
                onScroll={(ev) => {
                    console.log(this) //Constructor
                }}>
                {items}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
});
```

Binding **this** does not work.

```
onScroll={this._handleScroll.bind(this)}
```

Comment: I got the correct behavior in a sample app: https://rnplay.org/apps/otiPug Try to isolate things, something else must be changing the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I rewrote callback declaration in old fashion way (without ES6 Arrow Functions) it works as expected. Why So?!!!! If some one knows, please give me an answer.

```
var Frame = React.createClass({
    _handleScroll: function(ev) {
        console.log(this); //Constructor
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ScrollView
                ref='scrollViewH'
                onScroll={this._handleScroll}>
                {items}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see my answer for details on arrow function scope context and why this happens

Answer (score 4):

When you use the arrow function declaration, you are using 'this' available at the same level as your variable 'Frame', because es6 is inferring the context. This is explained in the article below, which states

> [Arrow functions] have implicit return and most importantly, they always use the value of *this* from the enclosing scope

The article gives a pretty decent explanation how binding syntax works in ES6 and how to get the expected behavior:

https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/